# Sizing of svg element using elements with negative coordinates

Tags: svg, cross-browser

When I create an svg element that contains objects with negative coordinates as shown in this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QGq3H/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="display:inline-block; height:100px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <svg class="svg-element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" version="1.1" height="60">
            <rect fill-opacity="0" style="fill-opacity: 0;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="60" width="100" y="0" x="0"></rect>
            <circle cy="-50" cx="-50" style="" stroke="none" fill="#000000" r="10"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome and IE the svg element has the same size as the visible part, in Firefox the svg is actually larger than the visible part. This is a problem when I want to get mouse coordinates relative to the svg element.

Which browser is correct? Is there a good workaround?

Comment: If I remove the circle from the jsfiddle in Firefox the size of the svg doesn't change. I don't therefore understand your issue.

Comment: The red rectangle does not change size. If you inspect the svg element using dev tools the size of the box will expand to the top left.

Comment: Both browsers are correct, feel free to report a bug in the Firefox dev tools though if that's what they do.

Comment: Updated my fiddle to ilustrate my problem better with some js

http://jsfiddle.net/QGq3H/5/